# C++ copy const char* to char*

Tags: c++, char, strncpy

I have a function

```
ClassA::FuncA(const char *filePath)
```

and want to copy this const char string* to a char*!

My solution:

```
char *argv[2];
int length = strlen(filePath);
argv[1] = new char(length +1);
strncpy(argv[1], filePath, length);
```

after this I have in argv[1] the desired chars but also some other undefined chars!

filePath:

> "C:\Users\userA\Parameter.xmlþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþîþKŸQyá•"

Whats wrong here? The length with strlen is OK!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like so:

```
argv[1] = new char[length +1](); // () to value-initialize the array
```

Your version:

```
argv[1] = new char(length +1);
```

only allocates a single `char` and value-initializes it to `length+1`.

Comment: `argv[1] = new char[length+1]; strncpy(argv[1], filePath, length+1);` could be faster for large lengths?! Well in most cases it wont matter i guess.

Comment: i pressed enter for a newline ...well does not work in comments, so my incomplete comment was visible for a second. you are to fast!

Comment: His use of `strncpy` is also wrong (but the syntax error in the `new` was well spotted).

Answer (score 1):

`strncpy()` copies not more than `length` characters. In doing so, terminating `\0` was not copied.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code:

- You need to add 1 to length after copying in order to copy null character (as strlen returns only number of chars without null character; see more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/)). So change code to:

  strncpy(argv[1], filePath, length + 1);
- You need fix how your array is being initialized as you are initializing only one character (and we assume you want full string to be copied). So:

  argv[1] = new char[length + 1]();

Notes:

- Please when you post also post the code that was used to print out data as problems such as these in a lot of cases depend on what you call to print out data.
- And at the end you might consider using just an array of fixed size that is initialized to maximum path. For max path size in windows checkout following [post](https://superuser.com/a/14887)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `strncpy`, rather than `strcpy`.  And
the way you're using it, it doesn't copy the terminating `\0`.

In practice, because `strncpy` may leave a string without a `\0` terminator, it's best to avoid it.  In your case, `strcpy` alone is fine, since you've just allocated a sufficiently large buffer.  In the more general case, you may have to use `strlen`, to ensure that the string you have fits in the target buffer (without ever forgetting to add 1 to the results, for the `\0`).

If the situation occurs a lot, you might want to write your own version
of `strncpy`, which works (i.e. guarantees a terminating `\0`, and
doesn't copy or write more characters than necessary).  Something like:

```
void
stringCopy( char* dest, int maxLength, char const* source )
{
    assert( maxLength > 0 );
    char* end = dest + maxLength - 1;
    while ( dest != end && *source != '\0' ) {
        *dest = *source;
        ++ dest;
        ++ source;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

(This function actually exists, under the name `strcpy_s` in C 2011, but
it isn't widely implemented; Microsoft has it, but I've not seen it
elsewhere.)